# Dynamic graph construction and visualization (Watts' "Small Worlds" α-model)

Tags: manipulate, graphs-and-networks, dynamic, core-language

I need some help in creating a *Mathematica* program for building and visualizing Watts' "*Small Worlds*" α-model.
This is a variant of the more known (and much more simple) β-model (also known as [Watts–Strogatz model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watts_and_Strogatz_model)), that I think is also implemented in Mathematica, i.e. with the command

```
RandomGraph[WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution[50, 0.05]]
```

but I think that the α-model is much more interesting for its intrinsic dynamic characteristics and I'd like to understand it better.
The rationale of the α-model is explained in the book:

Duncan J. Watts -  *Small Worlds: The Dynamics of Networks between Order and Randomness* - [1999]

Anyway there's a free preview snippet by the editor at *Google Books* site that explains it (from page 44 to page 48). It's [here](http://books.google.it/books/princeton?hl=en&q=These%20conditions%20could%20be%20satisfied&vid=ISBN9780691117041&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=These%20conditions%20could%20be%20satisfied&f=false) (click on page 46) so I don't need to re-explain it here (I just hope the link works also for not "*it*" (*it*alian) google users).

Till now I've managed to implement the algorithm in *Mathematica* with the following code:

```
Module[{n, k, w},
 (*
 The relevant parameters are;
 n: number of nodes;
 k: average edges per node (can be decimal);
 α: caveman (α\[Rule]0)/solaria (α\[Rule]\
∞) propensity;p: baseline probability for creating edges \
between "distant" nodes (the ones with no mutual friends);
 secondary derived parameters are;
 M: total number of edges, where M=Round[(k n)/2,0];
 iterations: total number of edges to be built after the substrate \
ring initial condition, where iterations=M-n=Round[(k n)/2,0]-n;
  *)
 Clear@rmat;
 Clear@prob;
 Clear@cumprob;
 Clear@ransamloop;
 Clear@matdyn;
 Clear@rr;
 Clear@αvalue;
 Clear@pvalue;
 Clear@newnode;
 debug = False;
 (*debug=True;*)
 n = 10;
 k = 9;(* it's better if (n k) is even*)
 αvalue = 0.1;
 pvalue = 0.3;
 M = Round[(k n)/2];
 iterations = M - n;
 activenodes = Range[n];
 fuconodes = {};
 ransamloop = {};
 samfwdcleaned = {};
 prob = Table[0, {n}, {n}];
 Table[ransamloop = 
   Flatten@Append[ransamloop, RandomSample[Range[n]]], {s, 1, 
   Floor[iterations/n] + 1}];
 ransamloop = Take[ransamloop, iterations];
 matdyn[0] = AdjacencyMatrix[CycleGraph[n]];
 mu[i_, j_, matr_] := Module[{count, k},
   If[
    Or[matr[[i, j]] == 1, i == j], 0,
    (*else*)
    count = 0;
    For[t = 1, t <= n, t++,
     If[(matr[[t, i]] == 1) && (matr[[t, j]] == 1), count = count + 1]
     ]; count
    ]
   ];
 r[i_, j_, matr_] :=
  If[Or[matr[[i, j]] == 1, i == j], 0,(*else*)
   If[mu[i, j, matr] >= k,
    1,(*else*)
    If[mu[i, j, matr] == 0, pvalue,(*else*)
     (mu[i, j, matr]/k)^αvalue (1 - pvalue) + pvalue]]];
 (* here starts the main loop *)
 For[w = 1, w <= iterations, w++,
  rmat = Table[Table[r[i, j, matdyn[w - 1]], {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}]; 
  fuconodes = {};(*there can be 0, 1, 
  or 2 nodes completed in the previous step *)
  Table[Table[
    If[Total[rmat[[i, All]]] == 0,(* 
     that means that node i is fully connected*)
     prob[[i, j]] = 0.; 
     fuconodes = 
      DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Append[fuconodes, i], 1]],(*else*) 
     prob[[i, j]] = rmat[[i, j]]/Total[rmat[[i, All]]]],
    {j, 1, n}],
   {i, 1, n}];
  (*above if is to avoid that a fully connected node show a prob=0/
  0 for all other nodes*)
  fuconodes = Flatten[DeleteDuplicates[fuconodes]];
  activenodes = DeleteCases[activenodes, Alternatives @@ fuconodes]; 
  todel = Count[ransamloop[[w ;; Length[ransamloop]]], 
    Alternatives @@ fuconodes];
  samfwdcleaned = 
   DeleteCases[ransamloop[[w ;; Length[ransamloop]]], 
    Alternatives @@ fuconodes];
  toadd = RandomSample[activenodes, todel];
  ransamloop = Join[ransamloop[[1 ;; w - 1]], samfwdcleaned, toadd];
  rr = RandomReal[];
  cumprob = 
   Table[Table[Sum[prob[[i, j]], {j, 1, u}], {u, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}];
  newnode = 
    FirstPosition[(cumprob[[ransamloop[[w]], 
      All]](*/.{p -> pvalue, α -> αvalue}*)), _?(# > rr &)][[1]];

  If[debug, 
   Print[{w, "ransamloop->", ransamloop, 
     "length of ransamloop" -> Length[ransamloop]}]];
  If[debug, 
   Print[Column[{w, (*"rmat->",MatrixForm@rmat,*)"rmat->", 
      MatrixForm[Round[rmat, 0.01], 
       TableHeadings -> {Automatic, Automatic}], (*"matdyn[w]->",
      MatrixForm@matdyn[w-1],*)"fuconodes->", fuconodes, 
      "activenodes->", activenodes, "todel->", todel, "toadd->", 
      toadd, "samfwdcleaned->", samfwdcleaned(*,"rr->",rr*), 
      "Curr node, rr, newnode->", {ransamloop[[w]], rr, newnode}}(*,
     Center*)]]];
  (*Print["Curr node, rr, newnode->"{ransamloop[[w]],rr,
  newnode}];*)(*matdyn[w]=matdyn[w-1];*) (*not necessary? *)
  matdyn[w] = 
   ReplacePart[matdyn[w - 1], 
     {{newnode, ransamloop[[w]]}, {ransamloop[[w]], newnode}} -> 1]];
 Print["final graph adjacency matrix->", 
  MatrixForm@matdyn[iterations]];
 Print[{"Total number of edges after each step of the main loop->", 
   1/2 Table[Total[matdyn[f], 2], {f, 1, iterations}]}]]
```

Then, with the following *Manipulate* command

```
Manipulate[
 GraphPlot[matdyn[t], VertexLabeling -> True, 
  VertexCoordinateRules -> 
   Table[{s -> {Cos[π/2 - (s - 1) (2 π)/Length[matdyn[w]]], 
        Sin[π/2 - (s - 1) (2 π)/Length[matdyn[w]]]}}, {s, 1, 
      11}][[All, 1]]], {{t, 0}, 0, iterations, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

I can see the network evolution with increasing *t* (the default parameters *n* = 10 and *k*=9 will lead to a fully connected graph for *t* = 35 given that the starting *connected* cycle-graph (at *t* = 0) already has 10 edges and that a fully connected graph with n = 10 has (10*9)/2 = 45 edges).

My problems are:

1. I've some basic knowledge of *Mathematica* but I'm absolutely no expert or advanced user.
2. The program is not optimized at all. It has to do much more calculations than I think are necessary. The processing time is acceptable for *n*=10 but becomes much longer for higher *n* (*n* > 20) and I'd like to check the result for *n* = 1000 (!) like in Watts' book reported simulations.
3. I'd like to pack the whole program in a single *Manipulate* command in which it should be possible to dynamically adjust the relevant parameters (*t*, *k*, *αvalue*, *pvalue* and even *n*) and see the corresponding result (my first naive trials to do that led me to infinite loops, errors and weird loop updates of the graph).

Any help?

Comment: I am not an expert by any means but have you tried `ParallelTable` instead of `Table`? Also consider replace `Append` with combination of `sow` and `reap`. Also, usually in Mathematica, `Do` loop is faster than `For` loop.

Comment: Thanks @Mahdi for your helpful suggestions. I'll try them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do some optimization of the code, using matrix operations instead of loops (or tables) whenever possible and changing the main loop from a *For* to a *Do* as suggested.
The *ParallelTable* command (also suggested) seems not to work inside a *Manipulate*.

The computation time has reduced by a factor of 10 (more or less) and it's now possible to build a graph with up to 50 nodes (about 8s wait).

The heavier computations are made in the external *Manipulate*: changing those parameters triggers the whole graph to be recalculated. The *t* parameter in the nested *Manipulate*, instead, shows the steps through which the graph is built till it's final degree and doesn't require a recalculation of the whole graph.

I think that I cannot do more than that (also given my limited knowledge of Mathematica) so I'm posting here below the code I finally came up with. Any suggestion for improvement of the code is welcome.

```
Manipulate[
 (*
 The relevant parameters are;
 n: number of nodes;
 k: final average edges per node (graph average degree - can be \
decimal);
 \[Alpha]value: caveman (\[Alpha]\[Rule]0)/solaria (\[Alpha]\[Rule]\
\[Infinity]) propensity;pvalue: baseline probability for creating \
edges between "distant" nodes (the ones with no mutual friends);
 Above parameters are set with controls in the external Manipulate. \
Changing one of above parameters triggers the recalculation of the \
graph;
 Secondary derived parameters are;
 M: total number of edges, where M=Round[(k n)/2,0];
 iterations: total number of edges to be built after the substrate \
ring initial condition, where iterations=M-n=Round[(k n)/2,0]-n;
  *)
 debug = False; (* with debug=True some partial data will be printed \
out during the main cycle to check the process;*)
 (*debug=True;*) (* with debug=True some partial data will be printed \
out during the main cycle to check the process;*)
 Clear@rmat;(*ramt: propensity matrix to establish a connection from \
node i to node j *)
 Clear@mmat;(*"mutual friends" matrix. Subscript[m, ij] is the number \
of mutual friends between node i and node j. 
 If i and j are directly connected than Subscript[m, ij]=0 *)
 Clear@matdyn; (* Indexed adjacency matrix of the graph during the \
mainloop. If matdyn[w][[i,j]]==0 then node i and node j are not \
linked at step w. If matdyn[w][[i,j]]\[Equal]1 then node i and node j \
are linked at step w *)
 Clear@newnode; (* node to be connected to the currently selected \
node (chosen in ransamloop) *)
 If[k > n - 1, k = n - 1];
M = Round[(k n)/2]; (* final number of edges in the graph *)
 iterations = 
  M - n; (* number of the main loop iterations needed to reach M \
edges after the initial graph (ring with k=2 and n edges*)
 activenodes = 
  Range[n]; (* list of the nodes that are not (yet) fully connected - \
updated during the main loop *)
 fuconodes = {}; (*list of the nodes that have become fully completed \
(that is linked to all the other nodes - updated during the main loop \
*)
 onesmat = 
  Table[1, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 
    n}]; (* a matrix filled with "1"s in every cell - useful for some \
matrix operation *)
 ransamloop = {};(* each node will be selected in random order, but \
once a node has been allowed to choose a new neighbour (newnode), it \
may not choose again until all other nodes have taken their turn once \
in turn. The choice will be a random choice weighted by the rmat \
propensity values. ransamloop is the sequence of nodes allowed to \
choose their new partners (newnode) and might be updated in each loop \
cycle whenever some node becomes completed after a new link is \
established *)
 samfwdcleaned = {}; (* forward part of ransamloop cleaned from fully \
completed nodes *)

 (*construction of the node sequence to reach M edges, that is M-n \
iterations *)
 Table[ransamloop = 
   Flatten@Append[ransamloop, RandomSample[Range[n]]], {s, 1, 
   Floor[iterations/n] + 1}];
 ransamloop = Take[ransamloop, iterations];
 matdyn[0] = 
  AdjacencyMatrix[
   CycleGraph[n]]; (* the starting graph is a simple ring graph *)
 loopnodecomplete = 
  False; (*boolean to track if the node chosen from ransamloop during \
the cycle has become a completed node *)
 connodecomplete = 
  False; (*boolean to track if the node linked to the node chosen \
from ransamloop during the cycle has become a completed node *)
 regularizer[matr_] := 
  1 - (matr + 
     IdentityMatrix[
      Length[matr]]); (*This function builds a matrix that, if \
multiplied element-wise by an adjacency matrix or by the rmat matrix, \
sets the diagonal elements and the already connected nodes elements \
to 0 to exclude the possibility of "self connected nodes" and \
"already connected nodes" to be re-considered for new connections *)

 (* here starts the main "Do" loop (from w=1 to iterations) *)
 If[debug, 
  Print[Column[{"======= INITIAL CONDITIONS: =======================",
      Row[{"ransamloop->", ransamloop, 
       " - length of ransamloop:" -> Length[ransamloop]}]}]]];
 (* begin of main loop *)
 Do[
  kprog = 2 + 2/n (w - 1);(* average graph degree at step w-1; 
   unsure if to use the final (target) k instead, 
   as Watts' book hints*)
   progr = Round[N[w/iterations 100], 1];
   loopnodecomplete = False;
   connodecomplete = False;
   todel1 = 0; todel2 = 0; samfwdcleaned = {}; toadd1 = {}; 
   toadd2 = {};
   mmat = 
    Table[Table[
       Total[matdyn[w - 1][[j, All]]* matdyn[w - 1][[i, All]]], {j, 1,
         n}], {i, 1, n}]*regularizer[matdyn[w - 1]];
   rmat = 
    If[\[Alpha]value == 0, 
     Table[If[mmat[[i, j]] == 0, pvalue, 1], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]*
      regularizer[matdyn[w - 1]],(*else: \[Alpha]value<>
     0 *)((MapThread[Min, {mmat/kprog, onesmat}, 
           2])^\[Alpha]value (1 - pvalue) + pvalue)*
      regularizer[matdyn[w - 1]]];
   newnode = RandomChoice[rmat[[ransamloop[[w]], All]] -> Range[n]];
   matdyn[w] = 
    ReplacePart[
     matdyn[w - 
       1], {{newnode, ransamloop[[w]]}, {ransamloop[[w]], newnode}} ->
       1];(* in the following section there is the possible cleanup \
of fully completed nodes from ransamloop and the corresponding \
updates of fuconodes and activenodes *)
   If[Total[matdyn[w][[ransamloop[[w]], All]]] == n - 1,(* 
    that would mean that node "ransamloop[[w]]" is complete *)
    AppendTo[fuconodes, ransamloop[[w]]]; loopnodecomplete = True(*,
    else: do nothing*)]; 
   If[Total[matdyn[w][[newnode, All]]] == n - 1,(* 
    that would mean that node "newnode" is complete *)
    AppendTo[fuconodes, newnode];
    connodecomplete = True(*,else: do nothing*)];.
   If[loopnodecomplete,(*update activenodes and ransamloop *)
    activenodes = DeleteCases[activenodes, ransamloop[[w]]];
    todel1 = 
     Count[ransamloop[[w + 1 ;; Length[ransamloop]]], ransamloop[[w]]];
    samfwdcleaned = 
     DeleteCases[ransamloop[[w + 1 ;; Length[ransamloop]]], 
      ransamloop[[w]]];
    toadd1 = RandomSample[activenodes, todel1];
    ransamloop = 
     Flatten@Join[ransamloop[[1 ;; w]], samfwdcleaned, toadd1](*,
    else: do nothing*)];
  If[connodecomplete,(*update activenodes and ransamloop *)
   activenodes = DeleteCases[activenodes, newnode];
   todel2 = Count[ransamloop[[w + 1 ;; Length[ransamloop]]], newnode];
   samfwdcleaned = 
    DeleteCases[ransamloop[[w + 1 ;; Length[ransamloop]]], newnode];
   toadd2 = RandomSample[activenodes, todel2];
   ransamloop = Join[ransamloop[[1 ;; w]], samfwdcleaned, toadd2](*,
   else: do nothing*)];

  (* loop print section in debug mode BEGIN ========================= \
*)
  If[debug, 
   Print[Column[{Print[
       "==================================================="], 
      Row[{"w = " <> ToString[w], 
        "current ransamloop->" <> ToString@ransamloop[[w]], 
        "length of ransamloop" -> Length[ransamloop]}, "; "], 
      "kprog = " <> ToString[N[kprog]], 
      Row[{"matdyn[w-1]->", 
        MatrixForm[matdyn[w - 1], 
         TableHeadings -> {Automatic, Automatic}], "mmat->", 
        MatrixForm[mmat, TableHeadings -> {Automatic, Automatic}], 
        "  rmat->", 
        MatrixForm[Round[rmat, 0.01], 
         TableHeadings -> {Automatic, Automatic}](*,
        "  probmat->",*)(*MatrixForm[Round[probmat,0.001],
        TableHeadings\[Rule]{Automatic,Automatic}]*)}], 
      Row[{"Curr node, newnode->", {ransamloop[[w]], newnode}}],
      Row[{"fuconodes->", fuconodes}],
      Row[{"activenodes->", activenodes}],
      Row[{"todel-> ", 
        "numtodel:" <> ToString[{todel1, todel2}] <> 
         " ", {If[loopnodecomplete, ransamloop[[w]], ""], 
         If[connodecomplete, newnode, ""]}}],
      Row[{"toadd->", toadd1, toadd2}],
      Row[{"samfwdcleaned->", samfwdcleaned}],
      Row[{"forward sample->", ransamloop[[w + 1 ;; iterations]]}]}]
    ]],
  (*loop print section in debug mode END  \
====================================== *)
  {w, iterations}](* end of main loop *); 
 Manipulate[
  Column[{Row[{"n=" <> ToString[n], "k=" <> ToString[k], 
      "\[Alpha]=" <> ToString[\[Alpha]value], Row[{"p=", pvalue}]}, 
     ", "], Row[{"MeanClusteringCoeff==" <> 
       ToString[
        Round[MeanClusteringCoefficient[AdjacencyGraph[matdyn[t]]], 
         0.01]], "L=MeanGraphDistance=" <> 
       ToString[
        Round[MeanGraphDistance[AdjacencyGraph[matdyn[t]]], 0.01]]}, 
     ", "], GraphPlot[matdyn[t], VertexLabeling -> True, 
     VertexCoordinateRules -> 
      Table[{s -> {Cos[\[Pi]/2 - (s - 1) (2 \[Pi])/Length[matdyn[t]]],
            Sin[\[Pi]/2 - (s - 1) (2 \[Pi])/Length[matdyn[t]]]}}, {s, 
         1, n + 1}][[All, 1]], ImageSize -> 600]}],
  {{t, iterations}, 0, iterations, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  TrackedSymbols :> {t}],
 Row[{Framed[
    Column[{Row[{"Graph construction computation"}, 
       Alignment -> Right, BaseStyle -> {Small, Italic}],
      Row[{Dynamic[
         ProgressIndicator[progr, {0, 100}, ImageSize -> {100, 7}]], 
        Pane[Dynamic[ToString[progr] <> "%"], ImageSize -> {30, 10}, 
         Alignment -> Center]}]}], FrameMargins -> {{5, 5}, {5, 5}}, 
    ContentPadding -> False, FrameStyle -> Red, Alignment -> Right],
   Control@{{\[Alpha]value, 0.75}, {0, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 
      4, 5, 8, 15}}, 
   Control@{{pvalue, 0.0001}, {10.^-9, 0.0001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 
      0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1}}, 
   Control@{{n, 20}, {10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40, 50(* takes too long*)}},
    Control@{{k, Floor[n/4]}, {Max[2, Floor[n/10]], Floor[n/4], 
      Floor[n/2], Floor[(3 n)/4], n - 1}, ControlType -> Setter}}, 
  "   "], TrackedSymbols :> {\[Alpha]value, pvalue, n, k}]
```

Comment: For general tips on writing fast Mathematica code, see this page: http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/